Shell script for finding global variables
How would one write a shell script that finds all the global variables in a given C program?
I don't need a long line like
global_vars=$(grep -E '^[[:space:]]*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[[:space:]]*;' "$c_file" | awk '{print $2}')

, but a genuine solution/ tactic.
I was thinking I could somehow check if the variable is encapsulated by curly braces, meaning it's not global, but I don't know how to implement that and it seems complicated.

A genuine solution? Use a C language aware tool.

To recognize and classify elements of C syntax, you need a C parser.  Regular expressions are not powerful enough.  I suppose that it's possible in principle to write a C parser using only the shell and standard utilities, but it would be huge and slow and pointless.

C does not have a global scope, and it is not clear what you actually want to find. If an object identifier is declared at file scope but with internal linkage (declared with static), do you want to find that? What about a static object declared inside a function? If an object identifier is declared inside a library header, such as <stdio.h>, do you want to find that? If all you want is object identifiers with external linkage, you can compile the source code to object modules and use various developer tools (like nm) to find the externally visible names.

int a; vs int a = 42;... Do you see the challenge you face? static int a[42] = { 37 };... Seems simple from a distance, but ugly when you look up close... /*foo*/ char ch;...

Note that there are tools that parse and index C source code already available for use -- some have been around for decades to support editor functionality. https://github.com/ffevotte/clang-tags might be a decent place to start.

(...even if no ctags or etags-type tool quite emits the output you want, the strategy of hooking into a real compiler is one you want to learn from).

Your best bet is to run Exuberant Tags: i.e. the ctags utility. Watch out: there is another ctags associated with Emacs. When you run ctags --version it should identify itself as Exuberant Tags.
Run ctags -R on the whole directory of the C program. Then in the resulting tab-separated tags file, you can look for entries that have a v code in the last column, like this:
gensymc[ TAB ]lisp500/lisp500.c[ TAB ]/^int gensymc = 0;$/;"[ TAB ]v$

The first column is the identifier. Then the pathname of the file. Then a search pattern which finds that line. In the last column we have a v which indicates "variable".
We can use Awk with -F'\t' tab separation to look for $4 == "v" records and output $1.
Note: if you end up needing the locations of the variables (exact line number) you can get ctags to record absolute line numbers in the third column rather than Vim search patterns.

It depends on how constrained the issue is. If you can't make assumptions about the coding conventions used, you will have to use a more powerful tool than regular expressions. If you can assume a few things, this is a starting point from a script I once wrote:
BEGINFILE {
    current_function = ""
}

# Start of function.
/^\w.*\(.*\)\s*{?\s*$/ {
    current_function = $0
}

# End of function.
/^}\s*$/ {
    current_function = ""
}

If current_function is empty (which in awk means it's "false"), then you are not inside a function. Then you can do something like this:
! current_function &&
        /<regex which matches non-pathological variable declarations>/ &&
        ! /<regex of things that might be confused for a variable, like typedefs, macros, etc>/ {
    print "global: " $0
}


If you mean to suggest that the OP adapt your actual code, then this answer would be much improved by detailing the code-convention assumptions on which it relies.  Also by addressing what kind declarations you would consider "non-pathological", and what a regex that matches those might look like.  Overall, though, I'm inclined to doubt that an approach that works only for the fairly narrow subset of the C language defined by a set of such simplifying assumptions would be of interest to someone asking such a general question.

This breaks if a function parameter is a "function pointer"... Too fragile, and does not even venture into helping OP with their problem. This is not an answer to this question.

Note in How to Answer the section Answer Well-Asked Questions, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "require too much guidance to allow you to answer in full" -- it's better to decline outright to answer questions that are too broad to permit a properly correct answer, and let the OP narrow their question until its scope is limited enough to permit a proper response.

And, beware of the effects of "preprocessor macros" and "not included badly coded header files" (with their own variable definitions).
